# How to hide a column for some users or groups

Tags: 2013, list, column

I want to hide a column for some users or groups. How can I do this with Sharepoint 2013 ? Is there a function to Hide or Show a column for specific users?

Comment: To hide where, List Forms, Views?

Comment: From a list Wiev - That noone can see this.

Answer (score 4):

Scenario : I wanna hide email address from SharePoint group.

```
<script type="text/javascript"language="javascript"src="https://my.abc.org/sites/SiteAssets/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></    script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
().SPServices({
operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
async: false,
   completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
   var xml = xData.responseXML.xml;

if(xml.search('sharepoint groups') != -1)

{
     var feedbackField = $("input[title=Email Address]");
     feedbackField.parent().parent().parent().hide();       
}
 }
);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Mathew, I've been trying this jQuery code you mentioned but there is an error in this line: ().SPServices({ . Can you fix this issue please ?

Answer (score 2):

Look for this solution:

https://sp2013columnpermission.codeplex.com/

Features:
Column Permission

- Hide or Read Only Columns in a List Forms (New/Edit/Display)
- Hide Columns in Views
- Hide Columns in Alert Me Emails
- Specify the permission for Users, SharePoint Groups or Active
  Directory Groups

View Permission

- Disable Views
- Automatically Disable Views in Custom WebPart Zones
- Specify the permission for Users, SharePoint Groups or Active
  Directory Groups

Another way - move add columns to list as lookup columns. So you can set up permissions for items in lookup list.

[Warning: List Permissions and Lookup Field Values – A Lesson in Security](http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=815f255a-d0ef-4258-be2a-28487dc9975c&ID=82)

Comment: And this isn't on on the box solution ? I must install this Extension ?

Comment: I can't do this by Sharepoint on the Box Solution for example Shareoint Designer or workflows ?

Comment: Because on this solution a column can be exported to excel so it can be read.

Comment: No, sorry, you can't do it. Sharepoint stil does not support field level permissions. There are some othe solution on the market, you cant try them.

Comment: Can You give them names  or link please.

Comment: http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-column-level-security.aspx

Comment: Out of the box, the closest you can get is to remove the column from any forms or views and then modify the permissions on any pages that still show it. As Ruslan said, there's no way to set permissions at the column-level without a third-party product or VS solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have a fairly simple workaround to apply "read only" to columns that requires no coding.

Let's say you have a list that can be edited by multiple people, but there is a master value on each item that should be locked down.  All you need to do is:
1.  Create your list as you normally would.  Assume that "Employee Name" is a column that you want to lock down.
2.  For the "read only" column, create a duplicate column called "Employee Name - Read Only".
3.  When setting up the column, tell it to use a formula.  The formula should be:  =[Employee Name]
4.  Now when you see the list, you will see two employee name columns; one can be edited, and the other is "read only" (and is just referencing the other employee name column).
5.  Next, create a view that ONLY shows the "Employee Name - Read Only" column.  Make this view the default, and when other people access this view, they ONLY will see the read only column.
6.  You will need to make sure to update the SharePoint list permissions so that users cannot create or modify views.  But at long as they are locked down to a view or views that hides the original field and only shows the read-only version, you should be good to go!

The same thing can apply if you want to hide a field; obviously you can restrict the view for users and just make sure the list settings do not allow users to modify or create new views (and make sure you or the list administrator DOES have a view that shows you everything).

I hope that helps some folks out - good luck and thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for hiding SharePoint fields

http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2011/09/hide-sharepoint-list-field-based-on.html