# Filter view for column for each indivual in list

Tags: sharepoint-server, filter

How do I filter the view for each user in a list group? So that only the individual user can view there inputted column like SS?

Comment: can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: Do you want the users only to view the items they have created themselves? There is an option for this in List Settings -> Versioning Settings: "Who should see draft items in this document library?"

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to hide the specific column for some users in the list view?

If that’s the case, it's not possible to use OOB filter in the list view, you can use JavaScript code to hide the column based on the current login user.

Edit the list view page and insert the Content Editor web part, add the JavaScript code in it.

There is a similar post about the JS code: [How to hide a column for some users or groups](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117149/how-to-hide-a-column-for-some-users-or-groups)